# Google Earth Engine: calculate percentile rank in ee.ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, vegetation-index

I am trying to calculate the Vegetation Productivity Index *sensu* [copernicus](https://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/vpi) in Google Earth Engine, which requires estimating the **percentile rank**. I haven't found any lead so far on how to do so, does anyone know how to do it or recommend a way to explore?

Given the example below, how would you calculate the percentile rank of the NDVI values in `img` compared to those in `ref`? What I am expecting is a value from 0-1, where the value at each pixel is the rank compared to all historical values for the same pixel.

```py
ref = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD13Q1').filterDate('2006-01-01', '2006-12-31').select('NDVI') 
img = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD13Q1').filterDate('2007-01-01', '2007-01-10').select('NDVI').first()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, [Percentile Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank) (not to be confused with Percentile function or Percentile) is expressed as percentage so, if you want values from 0-1 you can  only divide by 100. For calculating **Percentile Rank** (PR), the formula is as follows; where CF—the cumulative frequency—is the count of all scores less than or equal to the score of interest, F is the frequency for the score of interest, and N is the number of scores in the distribution.

[image]

In your case, the score of interest is **img** and all scores less than or equal to the score of interest are in **ref**. On the other hand, **MODIS/006/MYD13Q1** products must be divided by 10000 for obtaining corresponding NDVI values. I'm going to assume an arbitrary point in USA (-106.59086720561201, 38.81137001051776), however, when it is used this point with 'reduceRegion' method, some nulls values are produced with your dates range for **NDVI_ref** and they need to be eliminated. Following code determines PR based in above assumptions and formula, calculating its respective CF, F and N values for your date ranges.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry
  .Point([-106.59086720561201, 38.81137001051776]);

function divideImages(image) {
  return image.divide(10000);
}

var ref = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2006-01-01', '2006-12-31')
  .select('NDVI')
  .map(divideImages); 

var img = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2007-01-01', '2007-01-10')
  .select('NDVI')
  .first();
  
print(ref);

img = ee.ImageCollection(img.divide(10000));

Map.addLayer(img);
Map.addLayer(pt);
Map.centerObject(pt);

var getNDVIvalues = function(image) {

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var ndvi_value = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt)
    .get('NDVI');

  return ndvi_value;

};

var size1 = ref.size();

print("size list (including nulls)", size1);

var NDVI_ref = ref.toList(size1).map(getNDVIvalues);

var N = NDVI_ref.reduce(ee.Reducer.count());

print("size list (without nulls)", N);

print("NDVI ref", NDVI_ref);

var size2 = img.size();

var NDVI_img = img.toList(size2).map(getNDVIvalues).get(0);

print("NDVI img", NDVI_img);

var NDVI_ref = NDVI_ref.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', null));

var CF_values = NDVI_ref.map(function count (ele){
  
  return ee.Number(ele).lte(NDVI_img).multiply(ele);
  
}).removeAll([0]);

print("CF_values", CF_values);

var CF = CF_values.size();

print("CF", CF);

var F = ee.Algorithms.If(NDVI_ref.frequency(NDVI_img).eq(0), 1, NDVI_ref.frequency(NDVI_img));

print("F", F);

//PR = percentile rank
var PR = ((CF.add(ee.Number(0.5).multiply(F))).divide(N)).multiply(100);

print("PR", PR);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following image:

[image]

where PR of **NDVI_img** (0.4865) is 40.476190476190474. Complete list of **NDVI_ref** values are:

`0.4369, 0.475, 0.3211, 0.3146, 0.204, 0.4482, 0.2881, 0.4279, 0.5854, 0.5794, null, 0.6037, 0.0748, 0.6714, 0.655, 0.6442, 0.6564, 0.7149, 0.7389, 0.709, 0.4984, 0.5799, null`

They can be used for corroborating manually above formula for PR.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. I've been trying to adapt this to work on full images (ee.Arrays I guess?) rather than single points but I got a bit lost. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: **MODIS/006/MYD13Q1** products contain  global scale images (too big and too much masked pixels). So, I suggest to use your ROI for calculating the **Vegetation Productivity Index** placing a feature collection grid type on it. For each polygon of the grid, it would be determined its PR (mapping this feature collection; not by using an **ee.Array** object).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing a [reduceRegion](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion) or [reduceNeighborhood](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceneighborhood) using [ee.Reducer.percentile](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-percentile) as your reducer.

Your code would look something like this:

```
var ndviPercentile = img.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([90]),
  geometry: inputGeometry,
  scale: /*depends on the size of your input geometry*/,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Comment: Percentile rank is not **percentile function** or **percentile**. You can read correct definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank . On the other hand, he needs to calculate PR of **NDVI_img** in relation to **NDVI_ref** values; not percentile 90.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, thanks!