# Per-pixel percentile rank of ee.Image() compared to ee.ImageCollection() using "random" method as tie breaker

Tags: google-earth-engine, percentile

I'm trying to figure out how to use Earth Engine to calculate the percentile rank of an observation compared to a vector of observations. I would like to do this per pixel, and I want ties to be handled such that, if an observed value is tied with other values, a random percentile rank is returned between the minimum and maximum percentile ranks that define the block of ties (e.g., with 100 values and 25 of them tied at 0, which is the minimum, an observation of '0' would have its percentile rank calculated to be a random rank between 1/100 and 25/100).

I know I can build a cumulative distribution histogram with the ee.Reducer.autoHistogram() and the ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(). But I can't figure out how to work with the per-pixel 1x2 array representing lower bounds of the bin and the count of observations falling within that bin to get the output I'm looking for.

Eventually I'll want to map this function across all the images in an ee.ImageCollection() such that each observation is essentially transformed into a relative observation compared to all other observations at that pixel. I can definitely build the histogram (which can be approximate if needed) ahead of time.

My current approach has been to use the percentile reducer with 400 bands (all percentiles in increments of 0.25 percent) of the observed record, then match observed values to the closest percentile. This is a bit of a kludge, and doesn't let me handle ties very elegantly.

I've built a toy example using temperature data from 1000 items in the ERA5 Land dataset here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/73401a813f94c30751de7835cb2ab367

Here's the code copied here for convenience:

```
var era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY");
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.3094, 39.5307]);

var era5_small = era5.limit(1000).select(['temperature_2m']);

Map.addLayer(era5_small.first(), {}, 'Temperature example image');
Map.addLayer(pt, {}, 'Test point');

var era5_temp_min = ee.Number.parse(era5_small.get('visualization_0_min'));
var era5_temp_max = ee.Number.parse(era5_small.get('visualization_0_max'));
var era5_temp_seq = ee.List.sequence(era5_temp_min, era5_temp_max);
var era5_temp_seq_len = era5_temp_seq.length();

print(era5_temp_seq_len);

var era5_hist = 
  era5_small
  .reduce(
    ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(
      era5_temp_min, 
      era5_temp_max, 
      era5_temp_seq_len.subtract(1), 
      true
      )
  );

var hist_at_point = 
  era5_hist
  .reduceRegion(
    ee.Reducer.first(),
    pt,
    11000
  );

print(hist_at_point);  
Map.addLayer(era5_hist);

var test_img = ee.Image(era5_small.first());
var test_at_point = 
  test_img
  .reduceRegion(
    ee.Reducer.first(),
    pt,
    11000
  );
  
print(test_at_point); // 279.77

// Cumulative count at 278 (including values >= 278 but < 279) is 917 
// (so there are 917 values < 279)

// Cumulative count at 279 (including values >= 279 but < 280) is 966 
// (so there are 966 values < 280)

// This means there are 49 values >= 279 and < 280
// So the percentile rank of the 279.77 value should be a random 
// rank between 918 and 966, then divide by total number of images in 
// collection (1000) to get some value between 91.8 and 96.6
```

I saw this question, but it works only at a specific point and doesn't help with breaking ties ([Google Earth Engine: calculate percentile rank in ee.ImageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392533/google-earth-engine-calculate-percentile-rank-in-ee-imagecollection))